# require_grad = True in pytorch model despite changing require_grad = false for all parameters

Tags: pytorch, feature-extraction, transfer-learning, vgg-net, pre-trained-model

I am trying to extract features from pretrained model in pytorch and then use the features for further training.
I have imported the model and set the require_grad to false for all parameters as follow:

```
import torchvision.models as models
vgg_model = models.vgg19_bn(pretrained=True)
for param in vgg_model.parameters():
  param.requires_grad = False
```

Now, I defined my model, that extracts the features and then train on other layers as follows:

```
class VGGModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    '''Input Image Size: (227, 227)'''
    super(VGGModel, self).__init__()
    self.inception = list(model.children())[0]
    # self.inception = incept_model
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 512, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 5)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.4)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128, 5)
  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.inception(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=3)
    x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
    return x
```

But when I check require_grad for the model, it gives VGG layers as one which require require_grad as well.

```
model = VGGModel().to(device)
model.requires_grad_
```

output:

```
<bound method Module.requires_grad_ of VGGModel(
  (inception): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (3): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (4): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (7): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (12): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (13): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (14): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (16): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (17): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (18): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (19): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (20): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (21): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (23): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (24): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (25): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (26): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (27): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (28): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (30): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (31): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (32): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (33): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (34): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (35): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (36): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (37): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (38): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (39): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (40): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (41): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (42): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (43): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (44): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (45): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (46): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (47): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (48): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (49): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (50): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (51): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (52): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False)
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=5, bias=True)
)>
```

How do I prevent pretrained model from training again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the method:

```
model.requires_grad_(False)
```

You probably want to freeze only part of the network though, in your case you should change the fc1 attribute:

```
model.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(128, num_classes)
```

Where num_classes is the number of classes you have (you should at least unfreeze the last linear layer).